# Problem with mounting a sata ssd with a usb adapter on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: usb, mount, ssd, snap, usb-drive

I am trying to retrieve data from my old ssd. My old laptop broke because of a mainboard problem. I installed ubuntu 21.10 on the new laptop. And now finally I got a usb adapter for my old ssd.

when I plug it in it is automatically detected and drivers are loaded. great
But then two weird drives appear. 57mb drive and a 65mb drive.
65mb drive looks like a linux root drive but is definitely too small. Also home is empty, but I seem to remember that home was on a different partition.

mount gives me this:

```
 sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8065396k,nr_inodes=2016349,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1618144k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p8 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=17299)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap on /snap/bare/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_161.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_1810.snap on /snap/chromium/1810 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_72.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_2344.snap on /snap/vlc/2344 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_76.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2246.snap on /snap/core18/2246 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1519.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_145.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_547.snap on /snap/snap-store/547 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_13640.snap on /snap/snapd/13640 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1515.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1618144k,nr_inodes=404536,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1618144k,mode=755,inode64)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1242.snap on /snap/core20/1242 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2253.snap on /snap/core18/2253 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_1827.snap on /snap/chromium/1827 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/chromium.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_731.snap on /snap/firefox/731 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_558.snap on /snap/snap-store/558 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt type nsfs (rw)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-34-1804_77.snap on /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_14066.snap on /snap/snapd/14066 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_87.snap on /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1270.snap on /snap/core20/1270 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_747.snap on /snap/firefox/747 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/firefox.mnt type nsfs (rw)
```

I was expecting to see somthing like /dev/sda,  but no.

If I check with "disks" I see this
[disks screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNAiP.png)

what are these snap things. what does "(deleted)" mean?

dmesg:

```
[3132430.777821] usb 2-1: Product: M.2 SATA SSD DISK Device
[3132430.777822] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[3132430.777823] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 27170762020100025058
[3132430.782014] scsi host0: uas
[3132430.782447] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PSS9N008 GA27MC2          0214 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[3132430.783187] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[3132431.038566] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8138 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132431.089395] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8103 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132431.188600] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[3132431.188758] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#23 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[3132431.188760] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#23 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[3132431.188801] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132431.188819] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132431.188822] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132431.188822] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132431.188826] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[3132431.188827] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[3132431.188829] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[3132431.188830] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[3132431.188831] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[3132431.188834] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[3132431.248686] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132431.248691] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132431.248693] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132431.248694] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132431.248702] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[3132431.612665] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[3132431.637372] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 2.14
[3132431.637376] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[3132431.637377] usb 2-1: Product: M.2 SATA SSD DISK Device
[3132431.637378] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[3132431.637379] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 27170762020100025058
[3132431.641776] scsi host0: uas
[3132431.642331] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PSS9N008 GA27MC2          0214 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[3132431.643282] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[3132432.040566] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
[3132432.040736] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#11 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[3132432.040739] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#11 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[3132432.040790] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.040791] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.040795] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.040796] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.040801] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[3132432.040802] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[3132432.040805] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[3132432.040806] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[3132432.040808] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[3132432.040811] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[3132432.092615] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.092618] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.092621] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.092622] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.092629] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[3132432.432763] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[3132432.453639] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 2.14
[3132432.453642] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[3132432.453643] usb 2-1: Product: M.2 SATA SSD DISK Device
[3132432.453644] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[3132432.453645] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 27170762020100025058
[3132432.457953] scsi host0: uas
[3132432.458469] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PSS9N008 GA27MC2          0214 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[3132432.459461] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[3132432.864531] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[3132432.864698] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[3132432.864701] sd 0:0:0:0: tag#25 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[3132432.864742] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.864744] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.864747] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.864748] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.864752] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[3132432.864753] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[3132432.864754] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[3132432.864755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[3132432.864757] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[3132432.864759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[3132432.920603] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.920607] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.920609] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[3132432.920610] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[3132432.920617] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[3132433.169823] split_lock_warn: 5 callbacks suppressed
[3132433.169825] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8102 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132433.219012] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8138 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132433.268715] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8103 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132433.272583] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[3132433.297400] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 2.14
[3132433.297403] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[3132433.297404] usb 2-1: Product: M.2 SATA SSD DISK Device
[3132433.297405] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[3132433.297405] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 27170762020100025058
[3132433.301210] scsi host0: uas
[3132433.301762] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PSS9N008 GA27MC2          0214 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[3132433.302683] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[3132433.317827] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8494 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132433.367616] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8102 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
[3132433.417150] x86/split lock detection: #AC: CJobMgr::m_Work/8138 took a split_lock trap at address: 0xea0f7163
```

So my question is what is going on here? Is the adapter broken.
Is my old ssd corrupted?

Comment: Is it SATA or NVMe? And the adapter? It looks like an unsupported mode, given the errors. Unless otherwise specified those adapters support one or the other only (the M.2 connector fits both).

Comment: It is a nvme m.2 device. I wanted to add lsusb output but it didn't show any device name for the adapter. Just generic names.

Comment: Do you have a link for the adapter? Or brand/model?

Comment: The package says m.2 ngff(sata) ssd enclosure from Amazon. AOJUE DM201SUA-Gold USB 3.0 auf M.2 NGFF SSD Gehäuse externes SATA basiertes M.2 Solid State Drive Gehäuse (SATA basiert) https://smile.amazon.de/dp/B08GLMDPPC/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_glt_i_N0XQ2NXF8BVS91T7AQ2A?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: So that's exactly the problem as described in my first comment. If you have a NVMe drive you need an adapter supporting NVMe explicitly. Yours isn't compatible. Although the Amazon ad says it supports both that can't be the case. NVMe adapters are more expansive than that.

Comment: Oh no. Thank you for help.

Comment: I would sent it back and complain about false advertising.